# How do i solve this error? Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, escaping

I get stuck on the following:

Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in /home/xtremeso/public_html/mp3/includes/class/_class_mysql.php on line 116

```
        function safesql( $source )
        {
            if ($this->db_id) return mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->db_id, $source);
            else return mysql_escape_string($source);
        }
```

I already tried to mysql_escape_real_string but that doesnt solve the issue.
And ignoring php error messages via .htacces file doesnt work either

Comment: Did you fix it in the "else" as well?

Comment: I guess it's to switch over then. Make sure all instances of `mysql_` in all your code including DB connection have been changed to `mysqli_`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error message clearly said it .

change this

```
 else return mysql_escape_string($source); // you are using mysql here
```

to

```
 else return mysqli_real_escape_string($source); //will be mysqli
```

OBS: you should switch to PDO or MYSQLI as MYSQL `mysql_real_escape_string`  **will also be deprecated :)**

you are mixing Between mysqli and mysql .

EDIT: from your second error.

```
  mysqli_real_escape_string ($link ,$source )  // $link is your connection variable
```

[ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Indeed, i get again a error message when changed. now i got this error: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in: etc.. on line 116. How do i switch to PDO?

Comment: OP should show full code including DB connection. You'll be editing this unless your fingers cramp up. The "answer" lies in [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725040/how-do-i-solve-this-error-deprecated-mysql-escape-string-this-function-is-d#comment36466434_23725040)

Comment: hahaha you right :) , i was going to delete my answer as i got sucked :)

Comment: You know me by now. I never put in an answer when I don't see the whole picture ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes better , to dont edit 1000 edits :) .

Comment: Exactly. 1, 2, 3 edits at the most. Anything beyond that, I usually end up deleting.

Comment: I will just see what he will say after this last edit , from his error.

Comment: When i changed to ur edited post: 

now i got this error: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 1 parameters, to be mysqli null given in: etc.. on line 116

Comment: well, i just used this now..

<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
?>

Answer (score 1):

you need to connect mysql to the database before you use mysql_real_escape_string, this function doesn't work without mysql being connected to database.

Comment: No, that's mysqli_, not mysql.